# Example/tutorial for creating an input form using Android SDK

Tags: android

I'm looking to create a simple form with some textfields and a button using the Android SDK. Could someone point out a good example or tutorial for getting started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you haven't done so already, go through the [official tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html). In particular, [Hello Views, Form Stuff](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html) should be very useful. These tutorials are basic, but if you're looking for how to get started the official site is the best place to go.